# Making react-router's browserHistory work with Appcache without storing every path separately

Tags: javascript, url, react-router, single-page-application, application-cache

**TL;DR:** What I'm trying to figure out is how to configure my AppCache manifest so that *only* stores the root URL, plus any explicitly mentioned static files, and uses said root website as a fallback for any other URL, so that I can make it work with my SPA JS-based routing method.

I have an SPA that uses [`react-router` and browserHistory](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls) to create clean URLs as if they're all separate websites.

The catch to make that work is that when we hit refresh, the webserver must serve the same `index.html` website (and then use JavaScript to read the url and do stuff). Ok, that's easy enough.

Now I'm trying to make the SPA work offline with AppCache (because I have to support Safari). The app works a bit like how Google Maps lets you share locations with the URL: it lets users share views into data sets with specific view settings through a simple link: `/dataset/<dataset name>/<parameters>`. So I basically want it to work off-line from both the main url, but also any possible path like this.

After a lot of trial and error (and [Firefox's tools to debug the manifest](http://flailingmonkey.com/application-cache-not-a-douchebag/)) I got this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# dfb55f7a1c2f0ab09a93

/static/js/bundle.dfb55f7a1c2f0ab09a93.js

CACHE:
/
static/css/bundle.min.css

NETWORK:
*

FALLBACK:
/dataset/ /index.html
```

This lets me refresh and view dataset URLs when off-line¹ as desired! But now browsers don't just cache the root `/`, but also any `/dataset/<foo>/<bar>`. And if my users start passing urls around, they'll start caching each of those. That's not what I want either, because it's a waste of resources, and creates more complications when updating the App.

So where I'm stuck is how to configure my AppCache manifest so that *only* stores the root URL, plus any explicitly mentioned static files, while still letting me use said root website as a fallback for any other URL so that I can hit refresh while off-line.

¹ Well, assuming the dataset was visited an cached before; for that we use the [localForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/) library. This is all working fine does not overlap with AppCache as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution explained at this webpage worked for me:

http://dev.topheman.com/automate-appcache-offline-support-in-your-webpack-build/

The key thing that was different in the explanation here was this:

```
FALLBACK:
. offline.html
```

Specifically, *every* other site (and that includes [the page on the normally-excellent MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache)) would use this as their example:

```
FALLBACK:
/ offline.html
```

This invalidates the manifest (as can be tested in Firefox with SHIFT+F2, `appcache validate`). As explained in the *text* part of the MDN page:

> FALLBACK: The FALLBACK: section specifies fallback pages the browser
>   should use if a resource is inaccessible. Each entry in this section
>   lists two URIs—the first is the resource, the second is the fallback.
>   Both URIs must be relative and from the same origin as the manifest
>   file. Wildcards may be used.

Chrome doesn't care, but Firefox does.